# ¿Cómo ejecutar varias funciones según el orden de un array?

Tags: javascript, array, funciones

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar estas variables por su valor numérico (De mayor a menor), asignarle una función a cada variable y ejecutar estas funciones en el orden en el que se ordenaron las variables. No se como podría hacer esto, he intentado ordenar estas variables creando un array y ordenándolo con array.sort(function (a, b){return a - b}) el problema de esto es que no se como enlazar una función a cada una de estas variables para poder ejecutarla

```
   var h = 4; 
   var a = 8;
   var s = 5;
   var i = 1;
   var d = 2;
   var e = 0;
   var resultado = [c,h,a,s,i,d,e]
   resultado.sort(function (a, b){
   return a - b
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si utilizas un objeto para guardar tanto la funcion como el valor identificador de su posición te facilitas muchas cosas, con eso escoges el criterio de ordenamiento por ese identificador y mantienes una referencia a la función a ejecutar, un ejemplo podría ser lo siguiente:

```js
const a = { id: 2, fn: function() { console.log(2) } };
const b = { id: 3, fn: function() { console.log(3) } };
const c = { id: 1, fn: function() { console.log(1) } };

const fnArr = [a, b, c].sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id);

/* Ejecuta en el orden en que se ordenaron */
fnArr.forEach(elem => elem.fn());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias voy a probarlo para ver si me funciona

Comment: Ya lo probé y sí me funcionó muchas gracias